# Remember, not to work as well and restart

Tags: android, recompose

Recently I faced a problem with `remember` in compose; I have two simple, composable functions like the below:

```
@Composable
fun foo() {
    var x = remember { 1 }
    x += 1
    Text("$x")
}

@Composable
private fun MainScreen() {
    var state by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
    Column {
        foo()
        Button(onClick = { state += 1 }) {
            Text("Update Offer $state")
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that when clicking the button occurs, `foo()` recompose, and `x` increases, but this isn't work, and the `x` is always 2. Can anyone explain why it doesn't work as I expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using remember to store the initial value of x as 1. Remember is a composable function that returns a value that is remembered across recompositions. This means that x will not change unless the key changes. In your case, the key is always 1, so x will always be 1 + 1 = 2.

You should use mutablestate for x instead of remember. Mutablestate is a way to store values that can be changed and trigger recomposition when they do. You can use mutableStateOf to create a mutable state and delegate the getter and setter of the state.

Answer (score 0):

As [Ammirhossein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10214381/amirhosein) said, the problem was that `remember` works with reference and  `remember { 1 }` always returns 1; for fix the problem, I changed the code a little as below:

```
data class Test(var value: Int)
var temp = Test(1)
@Composable
fun foo(state: Int) {
    var x = remember { temp }
    Column {
        Text("$x")
        Text("${temp.value}")
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MainScreen() {
    var state by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
    Column {
        foo(state)
        Button(onClick = {
            state += 1
            temp = Test(state)
        }) {
            Text("Update Offer $state")
        }
    }
}
```